# Why is it that when I pass certain directory names to ls, it does not list their contents?

Tags: command-line, unix, zsh

I'm running macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. I use OhMyZSH as well as tmux. I don't understand why when I run `ls bin` and `ls etc` from `/`, the contents of the `bin` directory are printed but the contents of the `etc` directory are not. My `ls` is aliased to `ls -G` but I don't think this should matter.

I simply was expecting both directory contents to be listed. All I have tried is a simple `ls` of both directories from `/`, which yields the following:

```
# from root directory
> ls bin
# directory contents of /bin

> ls etc
etc
```

Comment: Try `file -h /etc`. Also, try entering `unalias ls`, and then running the same tests. The `-G` option does appear to have an effect on how `ls` displays symbolic links, even though according to `man ls` it's used to enable colorized output.

Comment: @Gairfowl thank you regarding `file -h`. also you're right removing the alias yields my expected functionality, strange.